# How can I get my current OpenGL transformation matrix in a Matrix4f?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

For the purposes of lighting, I need to get the current transformation matrix.

For example, `Matrix4f transMatrix = Get_OpenGL_Transformation_Matrix`

There are various answers on forums, but these either don't work or have people disagreeing with each other.

Comment: Is this modern open gl we're talking about here or deprecated pushMatrix() style opengl?

Comment: @LloydCrawley Pretty sure it's the deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

```
float[16] transMatrix;
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, transMatrix);
```

Comment: I don't want it in a float[] though - I want it in a Matrix4f. Is there any easy conversion? Also, is the MODELVIEW_MATRIX the same as the transformation matrix?

Comment: This is me being an idiot. But I should be able to help you. If you're using lwjgl then the transformation matrix is merely whatever matrix transforms the geometry to the position/rotation/scale you want. You should just be able to multiply/create this matrix in your shader, or alternatively do all the multiplication outside your shader then pass it in as a uniform. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I could do all the transformation and then pass it to the shader to use as location data, but that's a bit of a pain. Instead, I'd like to use all the glTranslate() and glRotate() calls I currently have, but then be able to separately get that transformation and pass it to the shader.

Comment: In other words, I would like to do `glTranslatef(1, 0, 1)` and then be able to get a transformation matrix with the location of `(1, 0, 1)` (as well as rotation and scaling etc).

Comment: Then if glTranslate etc and glGetFloatv still exist then do it the way I said above and pass the float[] to set the uniform for the shader. In "regular" opengl on desktop pcs you usually just pass a float pointer anyway i.e

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, transMatrix);

Answer (score 3):

This is purely from documentation, I have never used LWJGL. But I believe something like this should work:

```
// Create FloatBuffer that can hold 16 values.
FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

// Get current modelview matrix:
GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, buf);

// Rewind buffer. Not sure if this is needed, but it can't hurt.
buf.rewind();

// Create a Matrix4f.
Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();

// Load matrix from buf into the Matrix4f.
mat.load(buf);
```

Comment: And the modelview matrix is the transformation matrix, right? (The matrix that holds the location, rotation, and scale of the object)

Comment: You can also have a projection matrix. But your object transformations are normally part of the modelview matrix, yes. The enum used here matches the one you use as argument to `glMatrixMode()` before setting the matrices.